# .NET Web API 2 Owin.Oauth Possible to Avoid Two Requests?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I'm using Web API 2 with OWIN bearer token authentication trying to see if I can make one request instead of two. Normally a client will hit a /token end point, receive a token, and then make a second request to get data with the token.

I'd like to send a request to /orders with credentials, authenticate, and receive the data. Is this possible with Oauth.Owin? It seems counter to how it's set up. Thanks!